# List with onItemClick is not respond at all

Tags: android, listview, background-process, onitemclicklistener

My simple program using listview with onItemClick, is not respond when pressing on of the item on the list.

Could someone give me any idea how to check on these . I'm new on android and programming.
Below is part of my program class (ReadComments.java), that has the listview :

```
package com.lm.vciwhereabout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class ReadComments extends ListActivity {
    public final static String ID_EXTRA="com.lm.vciwhereabout._ID";
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // php read comments script

    // localhost :
    // testing on your device
    // put your local ip instead, on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    // or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL =
    // "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/comments.php";

    // testing on Emulator:
    private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://192.168.0.245/vciwhereabout/wabout.php";

    // testing from a real server:
    // private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL =
    // "http://www.mybringback.com/webservice/comments.php";

    // JSON IDS:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    // private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_POST_ID = "post_id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_FDATE = "fdate";
    private static final String TAG_TDATE = "tdate";
    private static final String TAG_FTIME = "ftime";
    private static final String TAG_TTIME = "ttime";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTBRANCH = "custbranch";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTNAME = "custname";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTADDR = "custaddr";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTCITY = "custcity";
    private static final String TAG_NOTE = "note";


    // it's important to note that the message is both in the parent branch of
    // our JSON tree that displays a "Post Available" or a "No Post Available"
    // message,
    // and there is also a message for each individual post, listed under the
    // "posts"
    // category, that displays what the user typed as their message.

    // An array of all of our comments
    private JSONArray mComments = null;
    // manages all of our comments in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.read_comments);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        // loading the comments via AsyncTask
        new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    public void addComment(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ReadComments.this, AddComment.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
     */
    public void updateJSONdata() {

        // Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
        // we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
        // to the json element name, and the content, for example,
        // message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..

        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Bro, it's time to power up the J parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
        // back a JSON object. Boo-yeah Jerome.
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

        // when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
        // try to catch any exceptions:
        try {

            // I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail." (success==1)
            // before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
            // mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
            // available
            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag

                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);

                String fdate = c.getString(TAG_FDATE);
                String tdate = c.getString(TAG_TDATE);
                String ftime = c.getString(TAG_FTIME);
                String ttime = c.getString(TAG_TTIME);
                String custbranch = c.getString(TAG_CUSTBRANCH);
                String custname = c.getString(TAG_CUSTNAME);
                String custaddr = c.getString(TAG_CUSTADDR);
                String custcity = c.getString(TAG_CUSTCITY);
                String note = c.getString(TAG_NOTE);


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                map.put(TAG_FDATE, fdate);
                map.put(TAG_TDATE, tdate);
                map.put(TAG_FTIME, ftime);
                map.put(TAG_TTIME, ttime);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTNAME, custname);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTADDR, custaddr);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTCITY, custcity);
                map.put(TAG_NOTE, note);



                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);

                // annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array
                // list
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */


    private void updateList() {
        // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
        //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
        //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
        //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
        //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
        //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter

                (this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.single_post, new String[] { 
                        TAG_USERNAME,
                        TAG_FDATE,
                        TAG_TDATE,
                        TAG_FTIME,
                        TAG_TTIME,
                        TAG_CUSTBRANCH,
                        TAG_CUSTNAME, 
                        TAG_CUSTADDR,
                        TAG_CUSTCITY,
                        TAG_NOTE }, 

                        new int[] { R.id.username, 
                R.id.fdate, R.id.tdate, 
                R.id.ftime, R.id.ttime, R.id.custbranch, R.id.custname, 
                       R.id.custaddr, R.id.custcity, R.id.note });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String username = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String fdate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fdate))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String tdate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tdate))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String ftime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ftime))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String ttime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ttime))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custbranch = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custbranch))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custname))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custaddr = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custaddr))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custcity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custcity))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String note = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note))
                            .getText().toString();

                    // Starting single contact activity

                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SingleContactActivity.class);

                    in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_FDATE, fdate);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TDATE, tdate);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_FTIME, ftime);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TTIME, ttime);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTNAME, custname);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTADDR, custaddr);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTCITY, custcity);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_NOTE, note);

                    startActivity(in);

                }     
            }); 
    }
```

And it should start SingleContactActivity class below , but never started:

```
package com.lm.vciwhereabout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
// import info.androidhive.jsonparsing.R;

public class SingleContactActivity extends Activity {

    // JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_FDATE = "fdate";
    private static final String TAG_TDATE = "tdate";
    private static final String TAG_FTIME = "ftime";
    private static final String TAG_TTIME = "ttime";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTBRANCH = "custbranch";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTNAME = "custname";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTADDR = "custaddr";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTCITY = "custcity";
    private static final String TAG_NOTE = "note";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact); 

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String username = in.getStringExtra(TAG_USERNAME);
        String fdate = in.getStringExtra(TAG_FDATE);
        String tdate = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TDATE);
        String ftime = in.getStringExtra(TAG_FTIME);
        String ttime = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TTIME);
        String custbranch = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CUSTBRANCH);
        String custname = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CUSTNAME);
        String custaddr = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CUSTADDR);
        String custcity = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CUSTCITY);
        String note = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NOTE);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_label);
        TextView lblFdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fdate_label);
        TextView lblTdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tdate_label);
        TextView lblFtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ftime_label);
        TextView lblTtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttime_label);
        TextView lblCustbranch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custbranch_label);
        TextView lblCustname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custname_label);
        TextView lblCustaddr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custaddr_label);
        TextView lblCustcity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custcity_label);
        TextView lblNote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note_label);

        lblUsername.setText(username);
        lblFdate.setText(fdate);
        lblTdate.setText(tdate);
        lblFtime.setText(ftime);
        lblTtime.setText(ttime);
        lblCustbranch.setText(custbranch);
        lblCustname.setText(custname);
        lblCustaddr.setText(custaddr);
        lblCustcity.setText(custcity);
        lblNote.setText(note);

    }
}
```

I already put the classes on the manifest as below :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.lm.vciwhereabout.ReadComments"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.lm.vciwhereabout.QueriesMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.lm.vciwhereabout.querywabyname"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.lm.vciwhereabout.querynameentry"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.lm.vciwhereabout.SingleContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
```

And this is the layout of the main class (ReadComments.java) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/widget60"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post_border_style"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    


<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/post_background_style"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo3s" />   


<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/box"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >


<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Username  :" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/username" 
    />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Fromdate   :" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/fdate" 
    />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Fromtime :" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ftime" />
    </TableRow>

     <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Cust/Br.Name :" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/custname" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Plus below is the layout of new intent that should be started (singlecontactactivity.java) . The name is activity_single_contact.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="10dp">
  <!-- Name Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/username_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"/>
  <!-- From Date  Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/fdate_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac"/>

  <!-- To Date Label -->

  <TextView android:id="@+id/tdate_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/ftime_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />          
  <TextView android:id="@+id/ttime_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />          
  <TextView android:id="@+id/custbranch_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />          
  <TextView android:id="@+id/custname_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />          
  <TextView android:id="@+id/custaddr_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />          
  <TextView android:id="@+id/custcity_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />                      
  <TextView android:id="@+id/note_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />              

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea is very much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

I have changed the code and put getListView().setOnItemClickListener in onCreate methot, but still get NPE .

The new updated ReadComments.java is below :

```
public class ReadComments<updateList> extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://192.168.0.245/vciwhereabout/wabout.php";
    private static final String TAG_MCOMMENTS = "mcomments";
    private static final String TAG_POST_ID = "post_id";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_FDATE = "fdate";
    private static final String TAG_TDATE = "tdate";
    private static final String TAG_FTIME = "ftime";
    private static final String TAG_TTIME = "ttime";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTBRANCH = "custbranch";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTNAME = "custname";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTADDR = "custaddr";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTCITY = "custcity";
    private static final String TAG_NOTE = "note";


    JSONArray mComments = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read_comments);

        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                     String post_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.post_id))
                                .getText().toString();

                    String username = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String fdate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fdate))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String tdate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tdate))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String ftime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ftime))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String ttime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ttime))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custbranch = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custbranch))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custname))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custaddr = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custaddr))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String custcity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custcity))
                            .getText().toString();
                    String note = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note))
                            .getText().toString();

                    Intent in = new Intent(ReadComments.this, SingleContactActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_POST_ID, post_id);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username); 
                    in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_FDATE, fdate);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TDATE, tdate);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_FTIME, ftime);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TTIME, ttime);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTNAME, custname);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTADDR, custaddr);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTCITY, custcity);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_NOTE, note);

//                  in.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));

                    startActivity(in);

                }       

          });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // loading the comments via AsyncTask

        new LoadComments().execute();
    }



    public void addComment(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ReadComments.this, AddComment.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
     */
    public void updateJSONdata() {

        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

        try {


            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                String post_id = c.getString(TAG_POST_ID);

                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);

                String fdate = c.getString(TAG_FDATE);
                String tdate = c.getString(TAG_TDATE);
                String ftime = c.getString(TAG_FTIME);
                String ttime = c.getString(TAG_TTIME);
                String custbranch = c.getString(TAG_CUSTBRANCH);
                String custname = c.getString(TAG_CUSTNAME);
                String custaddr = c.getString(TAG_CUSTADDR);
                String custcity = c.getString(TAG_CUSTCITY);
                String note = c.getString(TAG_NOTE);
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_POST_ID, post_id);
                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                map.put(TAG_FDATE, fdate);
                map.put(TAG_TDATE, tdate);
                map.put(TAG_FTIME, ftime);
                map.put(TAG_TTIME, ttime);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTNAME, custname);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTADDR, custaddr);
                map.put(TAG_CUSTCITY, custcity);
                map.put(TAG_NOTE, note);

                mCommentList.add(map);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter

                (this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.single_post, new String[] {

                        TAG_POST_ID,
                        TAG_USERNAME,
                        TAG_FDATE,
                        TAG_TDATE,
                        TAG_FTIME,
                        TAG_TTIME,
                        TAG_CUSTBRANCH,
                        TAG_CUSTNAME, 
                        TAG_CUSTADDR,
                        TAG_CUSTCITY,
                        TAG_NOTE }, 

                        new int[] { R.id.post_id, R.id.username,
                R.id.fdate, R.id.tdate, 
                R.id.ftime, R.id.ttime, R.id.custbranch, R.id.custname, 
                       R.id.custaddr, R.id.custcity, R.id.note });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

      }  



    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadComments.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Where About...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            updateJSONdata();
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            pDialog.dismiss();
            updateList();
        }
    }

    public void queriesMenu(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ReadComments.this, QueriesMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            dialogOnBackPress();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    protected void dialogOnBackPress() {

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReadComments.this);
          builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   ReadComments.this.finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();               
               alert.show();

    }

}
```

Right now, when clicking one of the item, there is a 'response' but got NPE, right after that.

Comment: This line: Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleContactActivity.class); should be: Intent in = new Intent(ReadComments.this,
                            SingleContactActivity.class);. Try to avoid using the applicationContext if possible. In this case always use the local ActivityContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below either of the below things will work
1. call the updateList() in  onCreate() method.
2. call
  getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String username = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username))
                        .getText().toString();
                String fdate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fdate))
                        .getText().toString();
                String tdate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tdate))
                        .getText().toString();
                String ftime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ftime))
                        .getText().toString();
                String ttime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ttime))
                        .getText().toString();
                String custbranch = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custbranch))
                        .getText().toString();
                String custname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custname))
                        .getText().toString();
                String custaddr = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custaddr))
                        .getText().toString();
                String custcity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custcity))
                        .getText().toString();
                String note = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                in.putExtra(TAG_FDATE, fdate);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TDATE, tdate);
                in.putExtra(TAG_FTIME, ftime);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TTIME, ttime);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTNAME, custname);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTADDR, custaddr);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTBRANCH, custbranch);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CUSTCITY, custcity);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NOTE, note);

                startActivity(in);

            }     
        });
```

in onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

You wrote onItemClick listener inside the updateList(). You need to write it outside the method then it works perfectly.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below code to get the value of the selected list item as shown below:

```
String userName = parent.getSelectedItemAtPosition(position).toString;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @MABVT, still the same, no response at all.

Comment: Try printing the value of the string userName and see what you get.

Comment: @Shivani Gupta, with : updateList() on onCreate, got NPE. And for the 2 alternative that you suggest, could you help a bit more specific , how to do that ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wrong comment to wrong person. Is this a dynamic listview? have you defined you list view in xml?

Comment: @Shivani Gupta, the 2nd alternative that you suggested, I have tried to do that, but got the message as attached.